# How to format a number from session in struts2

Tags: java, struts2, number-formatting

I have a number with more than 20 digits that I have to format it with comma separator. I have to read the value from http session. 
I used this kind:

```
<s:property value="%{getText('{0,number,#,###.00}',{<%=hsession.getAttribute("calculated_forfeit") %>})}" />
```

but it does not work and the error is: 
equal symbol expected 
!!!!!!!!!
getText format works for a variable but I'm not sure about the value from http session.
The technology is struts2.

please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put simple quotes in the scriptlet:

```
 <s:property value="%{getText('{0,number,#,###.00}',{<%=hsession.getAttribute('calculated_forfeit') %>})}" />
```

Anyway, struts2 provides a simple way to access to session attributes with `#session` variable.

```
<s:property value="%{getText('{0,number,#,###.00}',{#session.calculated_forfeit})}" />
```